# How can I define the spatial reference system for an hdf5 stack in python?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I'm new to h5py and my actual task is to create a hdf5-stack with MODIS subsets. I can create the stack with all the nice data in it but I'm not able to create or attach a spatial reference system. Goal is to load single datasets from the stack into a viewer like in ArcGIS and it should be placed at its right position.

How do I give the stack the right spatial/projection information?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach spatial coordinates to an HDF5 dataset with dimension scales - these are simply other datasets that are associated with your first dataset. If you want to indicate that a particular dimension has certain physical units you can label the dimension, which is done using the HDF5 dimension scale API: `H5DSset_label()`.

Dimension scales are possible in h5py, using `h5py.dims.create_scale()` and `h5py.dims.attach_scale()`, and `h5py.dims.label` to set the label.

For example, to attach two datasets to `foo.h5:/data` to specify the latitude and longitude, and that they are in degrees, you can first set their labels as follows (with f being the HDF5 file):

```
f['data'].dims[0].label = 'degrees'
f['data'].dims[1].label = 'degrees'
```

Then to actually add the coordinates, you first need to create a scale, then attach the dataset (where `f['phi']` is a pre-existing dataset with your coordinates in):

```
f['data'].dims.create_scale(f['phi'], 'latitude')
f['data'].dims[1].attach_scale(f['phi'])
```

You can then access the labels with

```
[dim.label for dim in f['data'].dims]
```

and the dimension scales themselves with

```
f['data'].dims[1][0]
```

or

```
f['data'].dims[1]['latitude']
```